# C# winform dialogue not shutting down program

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

I have made a mainForm (this is where my program actually starts) and a loginForm. the loginForm comes up as a dialogue when the program starts, so when I login correctly it shuts down and the mainForm pops up just as it is suppose to do.

When on I hit the red "X" (top right corner) on my mainForm my whole application closes which is good. But when I hit the "X" on my dialogue inlog form, my dialogue closes but my mainForm still pops up?

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\" + inlogNaamTextbox.Text + "\\Login.txt");
        gebruikersnaam = sr.ReadLine();
        passwoord = sr.ReadLine();
        sr.Close();

        if (gebruikersnaam == inlogNaamTextbox.Text && passwoord == inlogPasswoordTextbox.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Je bent nu ingelogd!", "Succes!");
            this.Dispose();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord fout!", "Fout!");
    }
    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("De gebruiker bestaat niet!", "Fout!");
    }
}
```

This is my login code

Comment: I would be great to see your code. How do you handle login form result?

Comment: kind of hard to tell if you don't show what code you are using.. we can't see what you see

Comment: @user3609166 definite candidate for a `Career Change` you have won my vote..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm should be following - in method `Main` on application startup show login form. If user logged in successfully then set [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of this form to `DialogResult.OK`. Then handle `DialogResult` returned by login form. If it's not `OK` then just exist application. Otherwise run your main form:

```
using(LoginForm login = new LoginForm())
{
   if (login.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
      return;
}

Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

Comment: And does this code help closing the program when I hit the X on the login dialog form? And where should I put it ? loginform or main?

Comment: why not try it and let us know vs asking a redundant question.. show some effort

Comment: @user3609166 you should put it in `Main` method of `Program.cs` file. Yes, applicatioin will be exited if you close login form without setting DialogResult

Comment: @DJKRAZE agree with you. It looks like 'show me where to copy-paste this code'

Comment: LOL this is why I get so short with some of these wanna be `coders` they expect the rest of the world to do their work for them your code is clear and to the point  Sergey Berezovskiy and I am going to def upvote your answer

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Thank you that did it. And to the other sorry i'll try to ask more direct questions in the future.

Comment: @DJKRAZE By the way. i'm just a beginner so I think these are normal things to ask. You were a beginner too at one point. Show some respect.

Comment: @user3609166 OK, glad to see that I helped and that you have intent to improve quality of your questions. I added link to `DialogResult` property which you should assign in login form (in case where you call `MessageBox.Show("Je bent nu ingelogd!", "Succes!");`)

Comment: No actually even beginners can express what they want or are trying to accomplish with better questions perhaps you should read up on how to ask / post a question on here.. and you gets Nil respect..

Comment: @DJKRAZE Whatever you want.